# Jsoup Select method returns null

Tags: java, web, screen-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the rating of each movie but I cant seem to use the select method in the right way. I am trying to get the **7.0** part from the webpage:

**http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/**

```
<div class="star-box giga-star">
        <div class="titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star"> 7.0 </div>
```

I am using this line in java:

```
Element rating = doc.select("star-box giga-star").first();
System.out.println(rating);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your selector is that you are using `ancestor child` selector instead of `.class` or `element.class` like `div.star-box`. Notice that to use multiple class you need to use `element.class1.class2` or just `.class1.class2` if you don't want to specify `element`.

Also if you want to specify `parent` `child` relationship you will have to use `>` so try maybe something like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/").get();

Element rating = doc
        .select("div.star-box.giga-star > div.titlePageSprite.star-box-giga-star")
        .first();

System.out.println(rating);
```

Unfortunately this will print

```
<div class="titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star">
  7.0 
</div>
```

so if you want to get only text contend from that element use `System.out.println(rating.text());`

---

BTW since there is only one element with class `star-box-giga-star` you can just use

```
String rating = doc.select(".star-box-giga-star").text();
```

as shown in [Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19453388/1393766)

Answer (score 2):

You can select an element by its class using `.star-box-giga-star`, and use `text()` to get the textual content of the element.

```
doc.select(".star-box-giga-star").text();
```